# View with derived value column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I'm having some trouble trying to make a view with a calculated average column, for every movie row I need an average rating based on all the ratings for this movie in the rating table.

Movie table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS streaming_db.movie(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL auto_increment
    ,name VARCHAR (100)
    ,description VARCHAR (1000)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

Rating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS streaming_db.rating( 
    id BIGINT NOT NULL auto_increment
    ,rating_score DECIMAL(4, 2) NOT NULL
    ,comment VARCHAR (255) NULL
    ,id_profile BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,id_movie BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW streaming_db.midia
AS
SELECT name,
    description
FROM streaming_db.movie a
INNER JOIN (SELECT avg(rating_score) AS averageRating from streaming_db.rating where 
rating.id_movie = a.id);
```

It was telling me that a derived table needs its own alias, and I don't know if that really gives me the average per row.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: It was telling me that a derived table needs its own alias, and I don't know if that really gives me the average per row.

Comment: . . That should be in the question.  However, the query will still be broken even if you add the table alias.

Comment: I'll add it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause.  Well, this is actually a real thing, called a *lateral join*.

But that is not your intention.  Move the logic to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT m.name, m.description,
       (SELECT avg(rating_score)
        FROM sistema_streaming_db.rating r
        WHERE r.id_movie = m.id
       ) as averageRating
FROM streaming_db.movie m;
```

Note that I fixed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names, which makes the query much easier to read.